# How to assure that the model only creates an instance only if another already exist

Tags: django

In the model I need to prevent orphan terms (synonyms or related of the preferred term) from being created using the same identifier code. For now I have the following:

```py
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.db import models

class TopographyCodes(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(
        max_length=5,
        primary_key=True,
        )

class TopographyFourCharactersDescription(models.Model):
    code = models.ForeignKey(
        'TopographyCodes',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        )
    term = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class TermType(models.IntegerChoices):
        PREFERRED = 1, _('Preferred term')
        SYNONYM = 2, _('Synonym')
        RELATED = 3, _('Related or equivalent')

    term_type = models.IntegerField(
        max_lenght=1,
        choices=TermType.choices,
        default=TermType.PREFERRED,
    )

    def is_preferred(self):
        return self.type in {
            self.TermType.PREFERRED,
        }

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            # We only support one preferred description per code
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['code'],
                condition=Q(term_type=1),
                name='unique_preferred_code'),
            ]
```

Now, if a is_main returns true (or would return true) the new term should be allowed to be created. I'm using a formset for editing this model, which presumes that it's created, but I would like the model to guarantee that no term would exist if there's no entry with the same code but preferred.

The database already have these kinds of problems and I would like to prevent them from occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your model have a relationship with itself, create it. Something like:

```
preferred_term = models.ForeignKey(
    'self',
    null=True,
    limit_choices_to={'is_preferred': True},
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
)
```

Now you can use a check constraint to verify that when term_type is not equal to 1, make sure that preferred_term isn't NULL:

```
class Meta:
    constraints = [
        [...]
        models.CheckConstraint(
            check=(Q(preferred_term__isnull=False) & Q(term_type__gt=1)) | Q(term_type=1),
```

Since this rule doesn't apply when your term is preferred, just make unconditional that the check passes when it's equal to one.